# How do I properly extend CountDownTimer class?

Tags: android, countdown, extends, countdowntimer, extending

I'm trying to extend CountDownTimer, but I have *"there is no default constructor in countdown timer"* problem.

```
public class CustomTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    // fields I need to use my original timer
    boolean still_down;
    View v;
    MotionEvent e;

    public ErjanTimer(View v, MotionEvent e,boolean still_down, long duration, long interval){
        // my original constructor
        this.still_down = still_down;
        this.e = e;
        this.v = v;
    }

    public ErjanTimer(long duration, long interval){
        super(duration, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> "there is no default constructor in countdown timer"

As you know constructor have same name as class name. but in current code class name is  `CustomTimer` and as you are saying `ErjanTimer` is constructor which is not valid. currently methods with `ErjanTimer` names behave like *methods with same names but different params*

So, just use `CustomTimer` instead of `ErjanTimer` for constructor :

```
public CustomTimer(long duration, long interval){
    super(duration, interval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class name problem which has already been suggested by ρяσѕρєя K were just typo, I would suggest an alternative answer.

So your class has below structure:

```
public class ErjanTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    ...
    public ErjanTimer(View v, MotionEvent e,boolean still_down, long duration, long interval){
        ...
    }

    public ErjanTimer(long duration, long interval){
        super(duration, interval);
    }
    ...
}
```

And having *"there is no default constructor in countdown timer"* error.

In this case, you must have calling to super also in your original constructor.

```
public ErjanTimer(View v, MotionEvent e,boolean still_down, long duration, long interval){
    super(duration, interval);
    ...
}
```